# EasyJet document check, internal Schengen flight: must the residence permit nationality match the passport?

Tags: schengen, paperwork, check-in, easyjet

Consider a traveler checking in for an EasyJet flight from one Schengen country to another.  The traveler holds a Schengen residence permit.  The residence permit shows the traveler's nationality, but the passport from the listed country is unavailable.  The traveler is a dual national, however, so wants to travel using the passport of the other country.  Is EasyJet going to accept the residence permit for the visa check if the nationality mentioned on the permit is different from the passport presented by the traveler?

Comment: Does EasyJet do document checks for internal Schengen flights? I thought that was a Ryanair thing.

Comment: What did your own research on Easyjet’s travel document policy reveal? https://www.easyjet.com/en/help/boarding-and-flying/travel-documents-and-information

Comment: @Traveller the closest applicable text on that page is "All customers travelling on international flights must hold either a valid EU/EEA/Swiss National Identity card or Passport, and, where required, a valid Visa," which does not answer the question.  Unless they consider "intra-Schengen" to be "domestic," which is by no means clear either.

Comment: @jcaron I don't know; I've never flown on EasyJet using a non-EU passport.